# Двойное подключение h файла

Tags: c++, c, arduino, include, стандарт

Есть сторонняя библиотека [IRRemote](https://github.com/Arduino-IRremote/Arduino-IRremote) для Arduino с таким заголовочным файлом `IRremote.h`

```c
#ifndef IRremote_h
#define IRremote_h
.........
#include "IRremoteInt.h"

/*
 * Include the sources here to enable compilation with macro values set by user program.
 */
#include "irReceive.cpp.h"
#include "irSend.cpp.h"
#include "IRremote.cpp.h"

#endif // IRremote_h

#pragma once
```

В `irReceive.cpp.h` есть такой код

```cpp
IRrecv IrReceiver;

IRrecv::IRrecv() {
    irparams.recvpin = 0;  // 44 строка
    irparams.blinkflag = false;
}
```

Теперь использование.

В своем `main.cpp` пишу

```c
#include <IRremote.h>

#include "Controller.h"

......
```

Все компилируется без ошибок. Но если я в `Controller.h` тоже добавлю инклуд

```cpp
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include <IRremote.h>
#include "Settings.h"

class Controller {
.....
}

#endif //CONTROLLER_H
```

То получаю каскад ошибок линковки

> CMakeFiles\Controller.dir\src\main.cpp.obj: In function `IRrecv::IRrecv()`:
> C:\PROGRA~2\Arduino\LIBRAR~1\IRremote\src/irReceive.cpp.h:44: multiple definition of `IRrecv::IRrecv()`
> CMakeFiles\Controller.dir\src\Controller.cpp.obj:C:\PROGRA~2\Arduino\LIBRAR~1\IRremote\src/irReceive.cpp.h:44: first defined here
> .........
> CMakeFiles\Controller.dir\src\controller.cpp.obj: In function `IRrecv::IRrecv()`:
> C:\PROGRA~2\Arduino\LIBRAR~1\IRremote\src/irReceive.cpp.h:44: multiple definition of `IRrecv::decode()`
> CMakeFiles\Controller.dir\src\AirConditionController.cpp.obj:C:\PROGRA~2\Arduino\LIBRAR~1\IRremote\src/irReceive.cpp.h:44: first defined here

Ошибок очень много, но все они ссылаются на одно место `irReceive.cpp.h:44`

`Controller.h` также инклудится в файл `Controller.cpp`, где находится реализация класса Controller

Как с этим бороться и откуда возникает эта ошибка? Ведь `IRremote.h` содержит include guard. Да, include guard не содержит файл `irReceive.cpp.h`, но он инклудится в одном месте в `IRremote.h`

Comment: что то мне подсказыает, что этот странный cmake скрипт рекурсивно подтягивает лишние хедеры.

Comment: А `Controller.h` вы же подключаете не только в `main.cpp`? Но и `Controller.cpp`? Не получается ли так, что эта штука `IRrecv::IRrecv() { ... }`, определённая в заголовочном файле, одновременно оказывается в нескольких `cpp` файлах?

Comment: @wololo Да. В `Controller.cpp` тоже есть инклуд `Controller.h`. А что делать? Переименовывать `irReceive.cpp.h` в `irReceive.cpp` и убирать его инклуд из `IRRemote.h`?  Я посмотрел, в `irReceive.cpp.h` кроме объявления глобальной переменной `IRrecv IrReceiver;` идет просто реализация класса `IRrecv`

Comment: В заголовочным файлом IRremote.h есть  #include "irReceive.cpp.h",  где ваше определение. Значит в "Controller.h" тоже есть это определение......

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а делать-то что нужно?

Comment: Ну, я бы сказал, во первых не изуродовать заголовочные файлы подключениями  файлов определения.  Но если это нужно, то, например, при подключении "Controller.h", не подключать  IRremote.h или не использовать Controller.cpp.  Просто все определите прямо в заголовочном файле.. А  еще лучше в заголовочный файл подключать только заголовочные файлы, чтобы не было повторного определения

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Я же пишу, что библиотека IRRemote не моя

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот этот код, о котором вы пишете -

```
IRrecv IrReceiver;

IRrecv::IRrecv() {
    irparams.recvpin = 0;  // 44 строка
    irparams.blinkflag = false;
}
```

оказавшись дважды в разных .cpp-файлах, приводит к появлению объекта `IrReceiver` и конструктора в двух файлах. Линковщик не знает, какой выбрать.

Если у вас С++ не очень старый - вас спасет просто добавление слова `inline` перед каждым из них.

Если старый - то лучше не заморачиваться, а перенести это все в отдельный .cpp-файл в проекте. Это самое разумное решение - чтобы каждый занимался своим делом: заголовочный файл содержал заголовки-объявления, а файл реализации - содержал реализацию.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Оформил баг-репорт автору библиотеки

Answer (score 0):

Оформил я [баг-репорт](https://github.com/Arduino-IRremote/Arduino-IRremote/issues/805). Если кто еще столкнется с этим багом в этой библиотеке, а баг все еще не закроют, то есть такой обходной путь:

1. Вместо `IRremote.h` нужно везде инклудить `IRremoteInt.h`. В этом файле описаны все описания классов.
2. **Ровно в одном** cpp файле проекта пишем `#include <IRremote.h>`. Тогда реализация подтягивается только один раз и проект компилируется.